# Split multiple cells into column

Tags: excel, vba

I have multiple cells with string like

for. ex cel A1

```
m2_10cm[0.10],m2_20cm[0.20],m2_5cm[0.05],m3[1.9]
```

and cell A2

```
m3_22[2.2],m3_19[1.9]
```

Hov can i split it to one column like

```
  Column  B
    Cell 1   m2_10cm[0.10]
    Cell 2 m2_20cm[0.20]
    Cell 3 m2_5cm[0.05]
    Cell 4 m3[1.9]
    Cell 5 m3_22[2.2]
    Cell 6 m3_19[1.9]
```

I will be apriciate for any help

Comment: Have you tried Text-to-Columns, then Copy->Paste Special->Transpose?

Comment: You might even try recording yourself performing a Text-to-Columns to see what it comes up with.

Comment: Thanks for fast response but in my situation it not enought. I need do it with formula because i collate it to data validation list

Comment: Would you like 1 formula is it ok to have multiple (maybe hidden) cells with intermediate results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using VBA code in Excel:

note: google how to a command button on the sheet and paste this as the code.

```
Option Explicit

' note: vbNullString is the same as "" (empty string)

Const START_ROW = 1
Const SRC_COL = 1    ' column A
Const DST_COL = 2    ' column B

' this gets triggered when the button is pressed
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    ' call the routine
    Call Go
End Sub

Function Go()
    ' assume the button is on the sheet to be processed
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
    Set ws = Excel.ActiveSheet

    Dim srcRow As Integer ' current row being processed
    Dim dstRow As Integer ' current row to put result in
    srcRow = START_ROW: dstRow = START_ROW

    ' keep going while column 'A' is not blank
    While ws.Cells(srcRow, SRC_COL) <> vbNullString
        Call Split(ws, ws.Cells(srcRow, SRC_COL), dstRow)
        srcRow = srcRow + 1
    Wend
End Function

Sub Split(ws As Excel.Worksheet, srcStr As String, ByRef dstRow As Integer)
    If (srcStr = vbNullString) Then
        'remove comment if you want blanks at the end
        ' ex. Apple,Banana, 
        '     will create 3 entries, notice the comma at the end 
        'ws.Cells(dstRow, DST_COL) = vbNullString
        'dstRow = dstRow + 1
        Exit Sub
    endif

    ' find ","
    Dim pos As Integer
    pos = InStr(1, srcStr, ",")
    If (pos = 0) Then
        ' no "," - put the whole string
        ws.Cells(dstRow, DST_COL) = Trim(srcStr)
        dstRow = dstRow + 1
    Else
        ' has "," - put the left part of the string
        ' ex: apple,banana,carrot
        '     put "apple"
        '     continue processing "banana,carrot"
        ws.Cells(dstRow, DST_COL) = Trim(Mid(srcStr, 1, pos - 1))
        ' move to next row and process the right of the string
        dstRow = dstRow + 1
        Call Split(ws, Mid(srcStr, pos + 1), dstRow)
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution where you need to have every other column hidden:
Say that you have the value in A1 then put in the following formulas:

```
B1: =IF(ISERR(FIND(",";A1;1));A1;LEFT(A1;FIND(",";A1;1)-1))
C1: =IF(ISERR(FIND(",";A1;1));"";RIGHT(A1;LEN(A1)-FIND(",";A1;1)))
```

B1 will then contain the first value in the list, C1 will contain the list minus the first value.  Now you can copy these formulas to D1 and E1 and they will now look like

```
D1: =IF(ISERR(FIND(",";C1;1));C1;LEFT(C1;FIND(",";C1;1)-1))
E1: =IF(ISERR(FIND(",";C1;1));"";RIGHT(C1;LEN(C1)-FIND(",";C1;1)))
```

Now keep on copying this formulas for as long to the right as you need.

Once this is done you can hide all columns that contain the shortened list, starting with C, then E, etc.

Comment: You could also in the same way do this down buy putting the formulas in A2 and A3 then copy them to A4 & A5, etc...
Then hide row 3, 5, 7 etc.